# Why/how is 'so, dass' used to introduce dictionary definitions?

Tags: grammar-identification

I know that *so, dass/sodass/so dass* is used to indicate a result and it often corresponds to English *so that*. We usually have two clauses where *so dass* occurs in the middle.

Examples:

> Das Wetter war schlecht, so dass wir wenig wandern.
>
> Sein Bein war so steif, dass er kaum gehen konnte.

However, my question isn't about the previous usage.

In PONS dictionary, *so, dass* is used to introduce many definitions.

Example: [Schön](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=sch%C3%B6n&l=dedx&in=&lf=) is defined:

> 1. so, dass es jdm gefällt.
> 2. so, dass das Wetter trocken und sonnig (und warm) ist.

I don't understand this usage of *so, dass* as I don't see an action and its result. How and why is *so, dass* used here?

Comment: so, dass = such, that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We usually have two clauses where so dass occurs in the middle.

There is a third use of "*so, dass*" (with the comma in between):

The words can be used to use a subordinate clause to express **how** something is:

> Die Straße war **so, dass** man darauf schnell fahren konnte.

Indeed this seems to be a short form of your second example:

> Die Straße war so *gebaut*, dass man darauf schnell fahren konnte.

Now you can use a subordinate clause to **replace** an adjective:

> Das Haus war schön.
>   Das Haus war so, dass es jmd. gefällt.

This is why "*so, dass*" is used to describe an adjective.

Comment: Maybe as a note on pronounciation: in this usage here, the pause between so and dass is usually longer than in the OPs examples.

Answer (score 7):

I think in this context "so dass" is best translated as "in (such) a way that"

> so, dass es jdm gefällt.
>
> so, dass das Wetter trocken und sonnig (und warm) ist.

would be

> in (such) a way that it pleases someone
>
> in (such) a way that the weather is dry and sunny (and warm)